# Windows Forms setup project file access

Tags: c#, permissions, installation

I have a Windows Forms project where I have added a setup project. In the `Applications` folder I have added some files that I want to include in the setup. I have, among other files, added a file called **settings.json**. In this file I'm saving settings from the user, but when I try to save text to this file I'm getting `Access to the path denied`.

I have clicked on the file in the setup project and the `ReadOnly` mode is `False`. Any ideas how to solve this?

It´s failing on this:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllText("settings.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: then check to make sure you have read/write access to the folder.. are you setting the folder / path correctly can you show the code where it's failing..? do you also have `admin rights` on the machine you're running it from ..try launching VS as `administrator`

Comment: It´s an application the users install, when I run it on VS it works. I have added the code were it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a User/User Permissions issue. Check UAC to see if it is not preventing you to make changes on some specific folder. Tipically when you create an installer, if you do not specify default location, it will go to c:/Program Files/... which will possibly have restrinctions if UAC is not deactivated

Also you can try to install the solution to another folder i.e: c:/MySolution